# Lock that has very low wake up latency

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

I am writing a reader writer queue, which requires latency as low as possible.  The frequency of writer is not high enough to keep reader busy all the time, so in common implementations, if queue is empty, reader waits on a lock and goes to sleep.  When somethings is put in the queue, the reader is woken up, however, this causes context switch and introduces latency.  Another approach is to use spin lock, but that uses atomic operations which essentially lock on bus and therefore causes a lot of load on bus, influencing performance of other jobs.

My question is, is there a way to put the reader in some idle state, without yielding CPU, but meanwhile doesn't cause heavy load to bus, and whenever something is in, it can exit the idle state and continue immediately.  The goal is to make the latency as low as possible from something put in the queue to the reader start processing it.  I can allocate a dedicated CPU core for the reader thread, so it is not a problem the CPU is wasted while the reader is idle.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can spin, or you can block, there isn't anything in between. `sys_futex` will be the most lightweight thing if you want to  block (but also the most unportable). Most of the time, one wants to not spin or block at all most of the time (but use atomic ops for lockfree modification of the queue) and block, never spin, when some "special" condition such as queue full or queue empty occur.

Comment: @Damon, It doesn't have to be portable.  Looks like sys_futex still has a wait queue and yield CPU when wait, doesn't it?  Basically what I want is, while waiting, the thread doesn't give up CPU, but running some loop running idle instructions which doesn't put loads to bus.  Whenever something is put in the queue, writer somehow signals the reader thread so it quits the loop.

Comment: You would have to be running on a multicore system, and would have to find a way to pin your reader process to a core with context switching disabled for that process so it could sleep without incurring a context switch.  You probably can't do this without some kernel-level hacking.

Comment: @icando: Running idle instructions in a loop is spinning, which is no good. Giving up CPU when there is nothing (nothing _useful_) to do is the right thing. `sys_futex` indeed does that, with the lowest possible overhead. What you _could_ do is implement a coroutine system (either using macro hacks or with `setjmp`/`longjmp`, there exist readily available C libraries that do this, too). All coroutine implementations are more or less ugly hacks, but running a coroutine if you don't want to give up CPU has the advantage that you can do _useful_ stuff in the mean time rather than spinning.

Comment: @Damon, as I said, the thing I want to optimize is the latency, so it is OK to waste the CPU while not doing anything.  Even with sys_futex there are still overhead for context switch and get in and out of kernel space when you put thread into sleep and wake it up, which are the overhead I want to avoid.  As for coroutine, when the coroutine is running, the reader can't get to run immediately, but wait for the coroutine to give up CPU, which is not acceptable at all.

Comment: @Damon, thanks for pointing out the instructions.  These are exactly what I need.

Answer (score -2):

If your concern is latency, just spins without lock. Make sure use keyword 'volatile' with your variable.

It won't have any disadvantages with BUS load or memory bindwitdh, because you're actually checking L1/L2/... Cache. And cache is synchronized between cores automatically.